# Message Processor unable to send message from message store to endpoint in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am getting the following error while my message processor trying to send the message from the message store.

content type used in proxy:

```
<property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="appliaction/soap+xml" scope="axis2" />
```

error in esb log:

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService} -  BlockingMessageSender of message processor [My_Processor] failed to send message to the endpoint {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService}
WARN {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService} -  Failed to send the message through the fault sequence, Sequence name null does not Exist. {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService}
```

I have changed my content type but now getting another error. Find the error log :

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender} -  Error sending Message to url : http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService {org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendRobust(BlockingMsgSender.java:198)
at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:144)
at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.dispatch(ForwardingService.java:288)
at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.execute(ForwardingService.java:128)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:622)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
... 12 more
```

Comment: Your value for the `CONTENT_TYPE` has a typo.

Comment: You'd help others help you by posting a minimal configuration that successfully reproduces your issue. It's impossible to say what's causing the issue with the information that you're giving out, since there really isn't any.